# VGG16 accuracy too low

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am trying to make a ML model with transfer learning (VGG16) in tensorflow, to identify images of medicinal plant from the image of the leaves. The problem is the accuracy of the model is not increasing it is as low as 0.05.

My dataset have 30 different folder. Each folder has been named after the class to which the images belong. I have 30 different class labels with name of the plant to which it belongs. The 30 different classes are - 'Alpinia Galanga (Rasna)', 'Amaranthus Viridis (Arive-Dantu)',
'Artocarpus Heterophyllus (Jackfruit)',
'Azadirachta Indica (Neem)', 'Basella Alba (Basale)',
'Brassica Juncea (Indian Mustard)', 'Carissa Carandas (Karanda)',
'Citrus Limon (Lemon)', 'Ficus Auriculata (Roxburgh fig)',
'Ficus Religiosa (Peepal Tree)', 'Hibiscus Rosa-sinensis',
'Jasminum (Jasmine)', 'Mangifera Indica (Mango)', 'Mentha (Mint)',
'Moringa Oleifera (Drumstick)',
'Muntingia Calabura (Jamaica Cherry-Gasagase)',
'Murraya Koenigii (Curry)', 'Nerium Oleander (Oleander)',
'Nyctanthes Arbor-tristis (Parijata)',
'Ocimum Tenuiflorum (Tulsi)', 'Piper Betle (Betel)',
'Plectranthus Amboinicus (Mexican Mint)',
'Pongamia Pinnata (Indian Beech)', 'Psidium Guajava (Guava)',
'Punica Granatum (Pomegranate)', 'Santalum Album (Sandalwood)',
'Syzygium Cumini (Jamun)', 'Syzygium Jambos (Rose Apple)',
'Tabernaemontana Divaricata (Crape Jasmine)',
'Trigonella Foenum-graecum (Fenugreek)'

I am using image `ImageDataGenerator` for augmentation. The generator is as follows -

```
#Definig ImageDataGenerator With Augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        shear_range=0.1,
        zoom_range=0.1,
        fill_mode='nearest',
        validation_split=0.2
        )
```

Yes, data is already splitted in into train, test and val. The main directory contain 3 sub directory and each sub directory has 30 folders with folder-name of same class to which the images inside belongs. The data is loaded using flow_from_directory with the following code

```
#Loading Training DS
def load_ttv_ds(train_dir,test_dir,val_dir):
  train_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
      train_dir,
      target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      shuffle=True,
      # subset='training'
  )
  test_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
      test_dir,
      target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      shuffle=False
  )
  val_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(
      val_dir,
      target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      shuffle=False,
    #   subset="validation"
  )

  return train_ds,test_ds,val_ds
```

While loading the images I have resized it to 256x256 pixels
i.e. `IMAGE_SIZE=256`,`BATCH_SIZE=16`
There are total 30 classes in my dataset.

Found 917 images belonging to 30 classes in train
Found 570 images belonging to 30 classes in val
Found 357 images belonging to 30 classes in test.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16

def build_model(lr=0.0001):
    base_model = VGG16(
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=(256, 256, 3)
    )

    # Freeze the VGG16 layers

    base_model.trainable = False

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())

    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    model.summary()
    return model
```

This is the model I am using. I am training it for 25 epochs and this is the output.

```
29/29 [==============================] - 36s 1s/step - loss: 5238.8730 - accuracy: 0.0556 - val_loss: 4.9995 - val_accuracy: 0.1211
Epoch 2/25
29/29 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 7077.9985 - accuracy: 0.0774 - val_loss: 6.2652 - val_accuracy: 0.0825
Epoch 3/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 7518.0254 - accuracy: 0.0720 - val_loss: 5.7178 - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 4/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 6460.3145 - accuracy: 0.0665 - val_loss: 5.5556 - val_accuracy: 0.1404
Epoch 5/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 10283.3672 - accuracy: 0.0774 - val_loss: 4.8519 - val_accuracy: 0.1509
Epoch 6/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 7203.8867 - accuracy: 0.0742 - val_loss: 5.3104 - val_accuracy: 0.1140
Epoch 7/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 7828.9897 - accuracy: 0.0752 - val_loss: 5.2341 - val_accuracy: 0.1175
Epoch 8/25
29/29 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 10705.5059 - accuracy: 0.0709 - val_loss: 5.3684 - val_accuracy: 0.1333
Epoch 9/25
29/29 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 8385.2148 - accuracy: 0.0774 - val_loss: 5.1373 - val_accuracy: 0.1246
```

The test accuracy is 0.05

What is the mistake in here? How can I solve it?

I have also tried it with different other models. EfficientNetB2 is giving quite good result of almost 0.9875. But we are strictly instructed to use VGG.

Comment: Do you preprocess the images with the appropiate function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input)? Also, I think you add to many additional layers to use frozen imagenet weights, but this is just a guess. The frozen weight are trained to give a prediction themself, not to be intermediate layers for 3 additional conv layers.

Comment: @mhenning I guess I am not using any wrong function, because the model is already working fine with other base models like efficientnet, inception and xception

Comment: Each net needs other preprocessing. In the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/VGG16) it is stated that it `will convert the input images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling`. Maybe other nets preprocess less and can work better with the data you provide. Low accuracy can come from really all kind of sources and you don't have an error message, so it won't hurt to try stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

try augmentation your data to generate more data. i think 970 images very low. use more data if you have or try augmentation techniques in order to have more more data and then try transfer learning.
also you might consider that VGG is not good for your approach. try using something like Resnet model or other models and evaluate your model. VGG might not be the good choice for your task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).